# Disable WebBrowser (IEApp) new tab/tab change event

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I have an app that installs a toolbar on IE. 
When a button on that toolbar is pressed, a processing function is trigerred that scrolls down the IE. 
Now until that completes, I wish to disable any click for new tab/ tab change.

Following is the snippet :

```
        try
        {
            string currentUrl = this.GetUrl();                
            MessageBox.Show("URL : " + (IEApp.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2).url);
            tabThreadID = this.ThreadID;  
            tabHandle = this.Handle;

            //...DISABLE ANY NAVIGATION ???

            processData();

            //...ENABLE NAVIGATION ???
        }
```

Kindly help on how can this be achieved?

Comment: How to detect a tab (new or existing) click in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying multiple solutions, event handlers, hooks, lockforegrounwindow(), setforegroundwindow, etc.. I could finally solve my problem by this post : [How to suppress global mouse click events from windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115578/how-to-suppress-global-mouse-click-events-from-windows/19291473#19291473)